# Tailwind how to add padding in t-head and body

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind I need to add some padding at t-head and t-body.

Its look like this right now white background and the text and background border merged I need to give spacing so headings have some padding with white background.

Code

```
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="font-bold text-2xl">History</div>
            <div class="text-xs font-medium text-gray-500">Last 6 months</div>
        </div>
        <table class="table-auto w-full">
            <thead class="bg-white">
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-left">Image</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Type</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Time</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Ammount</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Image</td>
                    <td>Car Insurace</td>
                    <td>10:42:23 AM</td>
                    <td>2500$</td>
                    <td>Completed</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read this page.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-spacing

simple e,g

````
<table class="border-separate border-spacing-2 border border-slate-400 ">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th class="border border-slate-300 ...">State</th>
     <th class="border border-slate-300 ...">City</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td class="border border-slate-300 ...">Indiana</td>
     <td class="border border-slate-300 ...">Indianapolis</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="border border-slate-300 ...">Ohio</td>
     <td class="border border-slate-300 ...">Columbus</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="border border-slate-300 ...">Michigan</td>
     <td class="border border-slate-300 ...">Detroit</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

simple add padding to heading table

```
<div class="p-6 bg-gray-100 w-screen h-screen">
<div>
    <div class="font-bold text-2xl">History</div>
    <div class="text-xs font-medium text-gray-500">Last 6 months</div>
</div>
<table class="table-auto w-full">
    <thead class="bg-white ">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left py-2">Image</th>
            <th class="text-left py-2">Type</th>
            <th class="text-left py-2">Time</th>
            <th class="text-left py-2">Ammount</th>
            <th class="text-left py-2">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Image</td>
            <td>Car Insurace</td>
            <td>10:42:23 AM</td>
            <td>2500$</td>
            <td>Completed</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: To add specific padding use as below
<thead class="bg-white p-5"> &  <tbody class="p-5">